# Using kogrid with json and knockout.mapping

Tags: json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I try to use kogrid together with json data which is mapped via knockout.mapping. At my WebApp it does work partly with Firefox and Chrome - no chance with IE9. Now I tryed to reproduce the problem with fiddle.js: But there it isn't working at all - no FF, no Chrome, no IE9. I can't see my mistake, does anyone other?

http://jsfiddle.net/g9YAT/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed version:

http://jsfiddle.net/jearles/g9YAT/2/

JSON.encode was turning your object literal into a string.

Comment: And I found the other bug: I forget to set the 'json: ' property: http://jsfiddle.net/g9YAT/4/  Thanks!